# Understanding the behavior of a quadratic function in two dimensions at a critical point (derivation)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion, quadratics

In his [MIT OCW multivariable calculus course](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter11/section01.html), Prof. Kleitman writes:

> (I) A general quadratic in two dimensions has the form $$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + g.$$  Such a function will have a critical point, at which its gradient is the $0$ vector, that is, where $$2ax + by + d = 0 \\ bx + 2cy + e = 0$$ both hold.
>
> (II) If we call that point $(x_0, y_0)$, we can write the quadratic function as in one dimension as
>
> $$a(x - x_0 )^2 + b(x - x_0)(y - y_0) + c(y - y_0)^2  + g'.$$

I'm unclear as to how he gets from (I) to (II).  Do the coefficients $a,b,c$ in (II) have the same values as they do in (I)?

If yes: I do not understand the derivation.  Writing $$d = -2ax_0 - by_0 \\ e = -2cy_0 - bx_0$$ I get complicated algebra which I cannot get to simplify to (II):

$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 -(2ax_0 + by_0)x - (2cy_0 + bx_0)y + g'$$ where $g' = f(x_0,y_0)$ does *not* seem to simplify to (II), and indeed seems like it could not, because there is no $x_0^2$ term.

Can you explain this derivation?

---

## Update

Based on ummg's recommendation to simply fold constants, I have the following derivation.  Each constant is folded into undetermined $K$ (which means the value of $K$ differs each line):

$$\begin{align*}
&ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + K \\
=\, & ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 -(2ax_0 + by_0)x - (2cy_0 + bx_0)y + K \text{ (at crit. pt)} \\
=\, &ax^2 +bxy + cy^2  - 2axx_0 - bxy_0  -bx_0y  - 2cyy_0 + K \text{ (distribute)}\\
=\, &ax^2 - 2axx_0 +bxy -bx_0y - bxy_0 + cy^2 - 2cyy_0 + K \text{ (reorder)}\\
=\, &a(x - x_0 )^2 + b(x - x_0)(y - y_0) + c(y - y_0)^2  + K \text{ (complete square)}.\\
\end{align*}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Constant terms such as $x_0^2$ can be added to the expression freely, since this is accounted for by the undetermined constant $g'$. That is, you can simly add any constant $k$ to your final expression; think of it as adding $+k-k$ (i.e. nothing) but including one of the terms in $g'$.

Comment: If you do the complete bookkeeping you will find that $g' = g - a x_0^2 - b x_0 y_0 - c y_0^2$ gives you the desired result. (Unless I have made a mistake.)

Comment: @ummg Thanks, I revised OP accordingly.  Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. You could also have gone the other way, starting with the expression in (II), expanding, and comparing with (I). This is what I did.